# How to get current Slider width when launch app - Swift/Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm working in an app on Xcode and Swift.

I set up a slider which width vary depends on device width. I use this element as reference to set up others width elements.

The problem is when i launch the app i don't get the dynamic width but the initial width instead.

Is there a way to get the dynamic width just when an app is launched?

Thnx!

Comment: Do you really need to get the width from the slider? "UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width", this will give you the device width. You can call this from anywhere

Comment: @VincentJoy Actually i do. Because i need to set it`s background image. And the slider width is not exactly the same as device width. Thanks for your help.

Comment: " i don't get the dynamic width but the initial width instead." where are you getting this? inside viewDidLoad() ?

Comment: Yes, just right there.

Comment: try this method inside view will appear or view did appear

Comment: That's exactly what i need. Thanks.